# Swap out html table for new table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to completely swap out a HTML table for a different one using javascript?
I know I can change the content in an existing table but can I have a pre-made table and just swap it in in place of a current table? and if so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Yes you can but you haven't provided enough info. How is the new one created?

Comment: `document.getElementById('yourtable').innerHTML = '<table><tr><td>tada!</td></tr></table>';`

Comment: Well in general; Have a trigger and replace the current table HTML with a new one. Easy right :D

Comment: Doesen't rly matter how it's created, I guess directly in JS code would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the two tables in that screen you can simply make one of them invisible using CSS `style="display:none"` and use javascript to access them and switch the display attribute between them each time you want to swap.

javascript code to switch would be

```
document.getElementById("elementID").style.display=''; (to show)
document.getElementById("elementID#2").style.display='none'; (to hide)
```

Comment: Thanks, good solution I never would have thought of :)